# I want o get one case per account

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have that query:

```
SELECT Id,AccountId,IsEscalated FROM Case WHERE AccountId != null AND IsClosed = FALSE ORDER BY AccountId,IsEscalated DESC
```

That return this data

```
Id AccountId    IsEscalated
1   1           true
2   1           false
3   1           false
4   2           false
5   2           false
6   3           true
```

But I want recive this

```
Id AccountId    IsEscalated
1   1           true
4   2           false
6   3           true
```

Comment: Please describe conditions based on which you want to get the desired result.

Comment: What is the business logic? 
Which case particularly you are looking in an account, if the account has more than one case?